# a connection attempt failed while importing json file

Tags: php

I am importing `json` file from the server. It runs absolutely fine. File is there in it's location. But, sometimes I am getting this error:

> a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

It's a `PHP` warning message.

**Code:**

```
$json_array_payment_method = file_get_contents(base_url()."assets/json/payment_method.json");
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: What base_url() function produce ?

Comment: It's the website URL. I am getting above error message sometimes only.

Comment: This is most likely because the site you are getting the JSON file from is throttling connections.  Are you using a shared web host from GoDaddy or other similar services?

Comment: You can read the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php. The problem seems to be some kind of timeout due to the server taking too long to answer the request in which case you can do nothing about it. From your code  you should be able to control the timeouts of the request and show a message or re-try in case of a failed connection attempt.

Comment: @LloydBanks: I am using windows azure (Basic Package). And file is in the same server.

Comment: @EricMartinez: Right now `default_socket_timeout` in `php.ini` file is : 60. would it be helpful if I change it to 900?

Comment: The base_uri have "http://" ?? I mean the path in file_get_contents  like this "http://example.com/asseta/json/payment_method.json" ?

Comment: @MohamedBelal: It's `https://`

Answer (score 0):

In your base uri try to remove "https" you are calling your own site assets file remotely in the script not internally you would remove the https and set only the path as a directory like `$base_uri="/public_html";`
then

```
file_get_contents($base_uri."/assets/json/..etc");
```

I think /assets/ directory have secret files so you can disable directory listing with this in your .htaccess file `Options -Indexes`